# How to make shift drag even slower?

Tags: interface

In blender you can use shift when moving something, this will reduce the amount it is moved giving you finer control. Is there a way to make the shift drag slower than it already is?

Comment: Currently this is hard coded, do you think it would be useful to make this a user-preference? (perhaps its annoying if applied everywhere)

Comment: @ideasman42 I was kind of surprised that this was not in the user preferences, I think it would be a good idea to let the user chose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> too. However, this only seems to work in a few places.

It worked in some number sliders, it didn't in others. It didn't work in any of the modal operators I tested

Comment: It seems like there's some inconsistency in the UI with these controls.  For example, selecting an object and hitting `G` `X`, you can then use `SHIFT` to slow it down (but not `SHIFT` `ALT`), while with the X location slider in the N-menu, you can use both.  For moving a strip in the VSE by hitting `G` `X`, you can use `SHIFT` (but not `SHIFT` `ALT`), while changing the Start Frame slider in the N-menu, you can't use either.

Answer (score 0):

In a blender, you can use "Shift" while moving something, which reduces the amount of movement and helps you control it better.
But currently, I've lost that function. Is there any way to get it back ?

Comment: You haven't really addressed the question. If you have a related question, please create a new post for it by clicking the **Ask Question** button.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/182869)